# p-adic logarithms with fixed precision

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, cryptography

Probably this is easy, but we would like to see it on paper.

Let $p$ be prime and $D,g,n$ positive integers.

Let $A=g^n \bmod p^D$.

Let $\log(p,a,D)$ be the p-adic logarithm with precision $D$.
In pari/gp notation: $\log(p,a,D)=$`log(a+O(p^D))`.
$\log(p,a,D)$ is efficiently computable.

Define $dlog(p,g,A,D)=\frac{\log(p,A,D)}{\log(p,g,D)}$.

> Is is true that $dlog(p,g,A,D) \bmod{p^{D-1}} = n \bmod{p^{D-1}}$?

We tested hundreds of large tuples for experimental support.

This might have some cryptography application for discrete
logarithms modulo prime powers.

We are interested in the discrete logarithm of $A$ in base $g$.

For this reason we generated hundreds of tuples $p,g,D,n$
and the code below correctly computed $n \mod{p^{D-1}}$.

Comments suggest constraints on $g$ but the implementation works
for arbitrary $g$.

**Adding pari/gp code due to comments**

You can run in it in a browser:
https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html

```
    /* discrete logarith modulo p^(D-1) 
    https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html
    */
{
dlog1(p,g,a,D=2)=lift(log(lift(a)+O(p^D))/log(lift(g)+O(p^D)));
}

{
tt()=
D=2;
setrand(1);
p=nextprime(10^8);X0=random(p^D);g=Mod(2,p^D);a=g^X0;
X1=dlog1(p,g,a,D);
print([(X1-X0)%p^(D-1)]);
}
tt()
```

Comment: A lot of misunderstandings in your question. $g$ must be $\equiv 1\bmod p$.  $\log(g+O(p^D)) = \log(g)+O(P^D)$, $\log(g^n)=n\log(g)$ and for $D>r=v_p(\log g)$, $\frac{\log(g^n+O(p^D))}{\log( g+O(p^D))}=n+O(p^{D-r})$ where $r=v_p(g-1)$ if $p$ is odd, $r=\max(2,v_p(g-1))$ if $p=2$.

It is not the most efficient algorithm to find $n$. The discrete logarithm in $(1+p\Bbb{Z})/(1+p^D\Bbb{Z})$ is a bit trivial.

Comment: @reuns You are misunderstanding. There are no constraints on $g$ and we checked hundreds of random g's. Added pari/gp code, which you can run online. Please check the code before claiming further constraints.

Comment: No, the $p$-adic logarithm is defined only for $g\equiv 1\bmod p$, even if you can set $\log(g) = \frac1{p-1}\log(g^{p-1})$ for other $g\ne 0\bmod p$, which is the same as assuming $g\equiv 1\bmod p$.

Comment: @reuns I am asking about finding n mod p^(D-1), no matter about the p-adic algorithm. Is your answer solution to this too?

Comment: You get $n \bmod p^{D-r}$ not $n\bmod p^{D-1}$. Taking $g=1+p$ for $p$ odd then $r=1$.

Comment: @reuns, what do you mean by "the discrete logarithm in $(1+p \mathbb{Z})/(1+p^D \mathbb{Z})$ is a bit trivial" ? Do you mean its image under $p$-adic logarithm is $0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We asked on the pari-dev mailing list and [developer Bill Allombert replied](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/archives/pari-dev-2104/msg00001.html)

> Your function is not defined for all (p,g,A,D).
> Otherwise this follows from the definition of the Iwasawa logarithm.

Since pari can compute the tests, the function dlog is defined for the cases of interest.